# MySQL: space-saving way to save a hex-value

Tags: php, mysql

I have long hex-values, which I want to save in MySQL:

```
2dbcd41104945306b6eaebfedfe665c2b3cb[...]
```

Currently, I am using the datatype "TEXT" in MySQL to store this values. 
But I think, it takes more space in the database, than it should.

For example, I could use base64_encode() before saving it (in PHP) and when I get the values from the database, I use base64_decode().

But is there something better than this?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is long hex-values in this context?

Comment: Up to 4KB, not longer. If the process of encoding/decoding is very slow, I´ll not do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store it as binary string in BLOB field, it will take 50% less space.

[UNHEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) on INSERT, [HEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) on SELECT.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it save to use with data up to 2KB-4KB? Also, wouldn´t it be faster to do this step (hex2bin or bin2hex) directly in PHP? Thank you very much.

Comment: It wouldn't save you any network traffic because escaping binary characters would add slashes and make it the similar size to original string. You could avoid that by using a real prepared statement, but in that case you would have to do a second network request. The difference in actual encoding time should be so tiny that it counts as microoptimization.

Comment: Thank you very much. I implemented it and it is working very good! :)